# Tag questions with specific exception classes, codes? Or go with a generic error tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

If a question refers to an error code or a exception type like `ORA-12345` or `IllegalArgumentException` etc., is it a good practice to add a tag with this information?

Or should a more general [exception](/questions/tagged/exception) or [error](/questions/tagged/error) tag be used?

I am tempted to add specific tags to some question so that users can simply click on the tag instead of typing.

Example: [exception EInoutError in the Data Module at 000C50BC I/O Error 103](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455822/exception-einouterror-in-the-data-module-at-000c50bc-i-o-error-103) has the [exception](/questions/tagged/exception) tag. If I add another tag with the specific exception class name, [einouterror](/questions/tagged/einouterror), users could click on the tag to see related questions where the same exception was reported. Users could then find possible causes for this specific exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Tags are only useful if they're useful.

Sorry - I couldn't resist the circular reference there, but it's true. When adding a tag to a question I always think "Would there be some commonality between questions that have this tag?". Take for example the .net `ArgumentException`, would there be value in two questions sharing this tag if they were, for example:

- I'm calling the `MessageBox.Show` method and receiving an `ArgumentException`
- Creating a database connection throws an `ArgumentException`

In this example, apart from the obvious "one of the arguments you're passing is wrong", there's *no* commonality between the questions and the answers are likely to be specific to the circumstances and the values that the OP is passing to the method calls.

> users could find possible causes for this specific exception

Many exceptions can have wildly varying causes, as I've suggested above, depending on context. So in short, **would the tag add value to the site as a method of categorising questions and allowing users to view questions**.

(*I'm well aware that tags like [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) are so generic as to contradict my argument above, but in the tag domain that exists for stackoverflow, tags such as [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) are almost "super" tags and thus my argument doesn't apply*)

Answer (score 2):

I can't imagine somone having a favorite tag, ignord tag, subscribed to or searching for the tag Error. Its simply to vaugue since every thing has errors. Its like having a tag code.

So I'm of the opinion that no, it  wouldn't help. But I could be wrong